# cygwin update cause "Error: could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable."

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I updated my cygwin using the [setup-x86_64.exe](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) tool (version 2.873) on Windows 7.
I needed to install some additional packages (mostly zip/unzip etc).

Since then, I am getting the following errors when I try to run the Cygwin Terminal (the shortcut points to C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -):

```
Error: could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable.  
DLL rebasing may be required. See 'rebaseall / rebase --help'.
```

[image: Screenshot]

I searched online how to run the rebaseall command they advise in the message. Essentially the recommendation was to start cygwin/bin/dash.exe and run:
`bin/rebaseall`
I did that a few times, I also used the -v comment, and no errors come back. Still I can't start cygwin.

I also tried running cygwin-x/XWin-server nothing happens.

I looked at the setup logs in `cygwin/var/log/setup.log` I can't see any error.

I tried to run the setup program a few more times reinstalling some of the packages I already had, that didn't help neither. 
Any ideas how can I get that to work?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the fix.

1. Go to you Windows Defender Security Center settings
2. Click on App & Browser Control
3. At the bottom click on the "Exploit Protection Settings" link
4. Go to "Program Settings" and click on the "Add program to
   customize" -> "Choose exact file path"
5. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe" and add it
6. Override and turn off the following: Mandatory ASLR, Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)
7. Click "Apply" and now everything should work fine.

Also add these other binaries from the same folder: expr.exe, uname.exe, grep.exe, rm.exe

Good luck,
Gabriel

Comment: don't have this app on my Win10

Comment: [The incompatibility between Cygwin and ASLR](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-06/msg00096.html) was the issue for me. If I understand it correctly, this solution leaves the system vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks at least within Cygwin if not more generally.

Comment: Yes, when i followed up the instruction from https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/6#issuecomment-361281467 the error is gone ... :D

Answer (score 5):

One of my colleagues has similar errors when openening the terminal from SourceTree (Mingw32), and also got errors when trying to `pull`, `rebase`, etc (anything not local). He solved it by uninstalling Sourcetree, using CCleaner to clean his registries (not sure if this was required), rebooted and installed Sourcetree again.

I know this is slightly different from the problem described by the OP, but it might still be solvable by un/re-installing and cleaning of registries, and this might also help future people finding this question with the Sourcetree issue (like I did).

**Edit:**
Another colleague had the issue as well, and he managed to fix it merely with a restart without any un/re-installation or using CCleaner.

Comment: Didn't work with or without running ccleaner to clean registry. But after uninstalling, running cleaner, restarting, and running ccleaner again, then reinstalling, it did work. So again I don't know if ccleaner was necessary, but restarting after uninstalling was.

Comment: @Andrew this seemed to be the route I had to go. Uninstall -> CClean registry -> Restart -> CClean again -> Reinstall SourceTree. Then I stopped getting all the errors.

Comment: What worked for me:uninstall SourceTree --> remove all files in App data relating to SourceTree --> reboot -> Install SourceTree

Comment: The **Edit** worked for me:  Just restarting my PC fixed it

Comment: I uninstalled SourceTree and used CClean as advised.  Doesn't work better.  And now installing SourceTree fails with "Installation failed".  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried the complicated sequence of restarts and CCleaner described by some of the other users here. Seems like the exact solution varies from user to user, but hopefully something will work for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've been suffering similar problems a lot recently.  I've been unable to determine the cause, whether it's due to a recent Windows7 patch or an update in the latest cygwin.  I'm in a tightly controlled corporate environment with only limited elevated rights, a lot of anti-malware and encrypted drives.  I'm using 32-bit Cygwin at present.

Issues for me began after I installed Git and Git-Svn packages, which required Perl and upgraded various other Cygwin packages as well.

Rebasing using rebase-trigger or rebaseall did not solve the issue for me.  Neither did re-installing and setup repeatedly raised errors in the post-install pahse when trying to do the rebase itself.

My first success was by downgrading Perl to the previous version, ie. down to 5.22.1.2 from 5.22.2.1.  After a couple of weeks the error returned, perhaps after a compulsory windows update and reboot.

My latest success has been achieved by ignoring the dash/rebaseall script and running rebase.exe directly as follows:-

1. Create a file which lists all cygwin .dlls in the /bin directory except cygwin1.dll and cyglsa.dll ie. 
   `$ cd /bin
   $ ls -1 *.dll | egrep -v '(cygwin1|cyglsa).*\.dll' >rebasedlls.txt`
2. Close all cygwin terminals, if you have any services running which use cygwin ensure that those are stopped also.  Check TaskManager and kill processes if necessary.
3. Open a cmd.exe window (it may help to use whatever elevated rights you can muster), change to the windows path of your cygwin /bin  directory (ie. the windows directory of `cygpath -wa /bin`).
4. Use rebase.exe directly to find the base address of the cygwin1.dll file:

`C:\apps\cygwin\bin> rebase.exe --info cygwin1.dll
/usr/bin/cygwin1.dll                          base 0x61000000 size 0x00500000`

5. Using that base address and the size as a guide I chose the next whole value up as my rebase base address, *0x62000000*.  No particular reason for this, just a hunch.  (The rebaseall script uses 0x70000000).
6. Use rebase.exe to fix all the .dlls listed in the file from step (1):

`C:\apps\cygwin\bin> rebase -b 0x62000000 -4 -n -v -t -T rebasedlls.txt`

So far, so good, my Cygwin is back to a working state again.

Comment: You simply may run `setup.exe` without installing/updating. It seems by default perform rebase. To trigger full rebase call `rebase-trigger full` before `setup.exe`.

Comment: @gavenkoa it does indeed, and _Rebasing using rebase-trigger or rebaseall did not solve the issue for me_

Comment: Your own steps may be necessary because of AntiVirus software. AntiViruses may map their dlls into Cygwin process address space with overlapping  with Cygwin base address hints and this should be fixed. More info https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/cygwin_dll_remapping_failure.md Cygwin can't control behavior of 3rd party software and you made good guess for base address (that couldn't make `rebaseall`). Keeping developer machine without AntiVirus may be a solution.

Comment: @gavenkoa indeed, as I wrote in the first paragraph:  _I'm in a tightly controlled corporate environment with only limited elevated rights, a lot of anti-malware and encrypted drives_

Answer (score 3):

From https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/cygwin_dll_remapping_failure.md

## Handling repeated failures of rebaseall to allow cygwin remaps

Sometimes DLLs over which cygwin has no control get mapped into cygwin
processes at locations that cygwin has chosen for its libraries.
This has been seen primarily with anti-virus DLLs. When this occurs,
cygwin must be instructed during the rebase to avoid the area of
memory where that DLL is mapped.

### Background

Some background for this is available on
http://www.dont-panic.cc/capi/2007/10/29/git-svn-fails-with-fatal-error-unable-to-remap/

Because of unix fork semantics (presumably), cygwin libraries must be
mapped in the same location in both parent and child of a fork.  All
cygwin libraries have hints in them as to where they should be mapped
in a processes address space; if those hints are followed, each
library will be mapped in the same location in both address spaces.
However, Windows is perfectly happy mapping a DLL anywhere in the
address space; the hint is not considered controlling.  The remapping
error occurs when a cygwin process starts and one of its libraries
cannot be mapped to the location specified by its hint.

/usr/bin/rebaseall changes the DLL hints for all of the cygwin
libraries so that there are no inter-library conflicts; it does this
by choosing a contiguous but not overlapping library layout starting
at a base address and working down.  This process makes sure there are
no intra-cygwin conflicts, but cannot deal with conflicts with
external DLLs that are in cygwin process address spaces
(e.g. anti-virus DLLs).

To handle this case, you need to figure out what the problematic
non-cygwin library is, where it is in the address space, and do the
rebase all so that no cygwin hints map libraries to that location.

### Details

- Download the ListDLLs executable from
  [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx)
- Run it as administrator while some cygwin commands are running.
- Scan the output for the cygwin process (identifiable by the command) and for
  DLLs in that process that do not look like cygwin DLLs (like an AV). Note
  the location of those libraries (there will usually only be the one).
- Pick an address space location lower than its starting address.
- Quit all cygwin processes.
- Run a windows command shell as administrator
- cd in \cygwin\bin
- Run `ash /usr/bin/rebaseall -b <base address>` (This command can also take a
  `-v` flag if you want to see the DLL layout.)

That should fix the problem.

### Failed rebaseall

If you pick a base address that is too low, you may end up with a broken cygwin
install. You can reinstall it by running cygwin's setup.exe again, and on the
package selection page, clicking the "All" entry to Reinstall. You may have to
do this twice, as you may get errors on the first reinstall pass.

Comment: Hi @gavenkoa, I ran ListDLLs on Windows 10 with the Cygwin bash shell running, and I got this result https://pastebin.com/raw/TNGefSRz but I'm not sure which dll's are expected. There seem to be many non-Cygwin dlls. Also, what did you mean by "lower" address? Does that mean numerically lesser or numerically greater address? Thanks

Comment: I also compiled a simple infinite loop executable in Cygwin and here are the Listdll results https://pastebin.com/raw/uxpEarUj

Answer (score 1):

I have Administrator access to my PC. For me the solution to this was to run the Cygwin session as Administrator -- right the icon, run as administrator, as shown here:

[image]

After running as Administrator the first time, new Cygwin sessions started up without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rebase utility that triggers the rebase as post-setup phase.

From dash or bash:

```
/usr/bin/rebase-trigger full
```

close all process and run again setup-x86_64.exe.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall it,
and install the software for 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted 3 times, and then it was fine. wtf Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

This exact same error message has various causes, not all of them related to setup-x86_64.exe, although I have seen it in that context as well.  But if rebaseall didn't fix your problem, here's a suggestion that might work.

In the case I saw this morning, it turned out to have been caused by having a couple of processes that continued to run after I exited the mintty terminal emulator.   My hunch is that these zombie processes prevent the console from being recycled.  In my case, the two processes were determined experimentally, by reviewing a list of running processes for stray processes that are no longer needed.  I found the two processes that were blocking me by reviewing the list of running tasks.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tasklist | grep Console

CobraWinLDTP.exe             31844 Console                    1     43,600 K
geckodriver.exe              52640 Console                    1     32,164 K

C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /F /PID 31844
SUCCESS: The process with PID 31844 has been terminated.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /F /PID 52640
SUCCESS: The process with PID 52640 has been terminated.
```

I saw on some other stackoverflow questions that git is often the zombie process that causes this symptom (for some users).   Unfortunately, any residual process that survives after your console session is closed can cause this problem, so you have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to The Task manager
2. Kill 'Git for Windows' process
3. Reopen your git bash

It seems that all is working fine.

NOTE: In case you don't find 'Git for Windows' process and still have to face the same just kill 'Node.js: Server-side JavaScript' process instead

Answer (score 0):

If you have turned `Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)` on in Exploit protection of Windows Security, then you can turn it off by selecting `Use default (Off)` to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My instance of this problem was also related to having turned on 'force randomization for images' in the Windows Security exploit protection settings.

After you change the setting back to the default off position and reset, you will have to run Git as an administrator in order to effect directory changes which apparently require elevated permission.

I wasn't able to determine a way to allow that setting to be turned on and not get this issue with Git though I played around with it for a while unsuccessfully.

Turning even optional security features off to get a single program working seems like a last resort option to me.  However, this isn't just any program either.